# Import Text File Data to Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks as follows:

```
attribute id - value
64           - 109.txt
109          - some other data
110          - some other data
64           - 110.txt
109          - some other data
110          - some other data
```

I then have a php script that can read the text document here:

`<?php
$lines = file('http://www.mywebsite.com/files.txt');
?>`

I need to grab that text file from my database, where attribute id = 64 leaving the "other data" as it is. Then open the txt file in php and put the contents back into that exact field it got them from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Simon

Also: the table name is "mage_catalogsearch_fulltext" attribute_id and value are the correct names for the columns

The reason for me doing this is the product descriptions are all inside those text documents, and I need to suck them out and put the actual content into that field rather than the file reference

In ref to Jaspers post: is not me asking someone to write it but more give direction on the Query I should look at running to return each result and update each result for each reference.

Comment: It doesn't look good that you have duplicate ids!

Comment: `I was wondering if someone could help me write a php script ....` Seems like *gimme teh codes* question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this isn't a place to find people to write your code, let me offer you with an idea how to approach it so you can write it yourself. If you get into problems along the way, this is a good place to help once you have specific questions.

1. Start off by doing a select on all the fields you want to change
2. Do the following for each of the rows your select returned:

   1. Check the last few letters of the `value` field to see if they are `.txt`
   2. If they aren't, don't do any of the following and just skip ahead to the next entry
   3. Otherwise, interpret the value of that field as a file name and read that file into a variable
   4. Do an update on your database where you set the `value` of the current entry to the contents of the file instead of the filename

Comment: Hi Jasper, thankyou for the reply. Sorry it was not so much me asking for someone to write it, it was more me asking for someone to help me write it. My php is fine but its the MYSQL that I get stuck on. Is it possible to run a query for each result? So my fear is I update all fields with one text document and not for each grab each text file.

Comment: In that case, you're generally better off trying and going here when you get stuck, this place gets a lot friendlier when you've got code and a concrete problem. You can very well do an update for each row, and you just make sure you only update one entry in your `WHERE` clause. Normally, you would use the `id` field (or something similar) to make sure you only update a single row. However, seeing that you have duplicate ids here, you might have to use both the id and the old value of the `value` column (though a redesign with some sort of `primary key` is a better idea).

Comment: I see, so I could ref the original value field (as these are all uniques) and only change WHERE value = $fileupdating (value = $fileupdating) etc?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly. I think it would be more like `"UPDATE table SET value = '" . escape($readFromFile) . '" WHERE value = '" . escape($originalValue) . "'";` though. And I want to urge you once again to rethink your database design, as that's actually a better option here. (Oh, and `escape()` is pseudo-code.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that query looks about right. Also the database structure is the Magento CMS not much control on that one. Total nightmare to do manual backend edits like this.